# another question on the Manin-Drinfeld theorem

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, modular-forms

A few days ago I asked a question about possible higher dimensional generalizations of the Manin-Drinfeld theorem. Let me come back to the classical statement.

It says that a divisor on the modular curve which is supported on the cusps is torsion. My question is: is there an explicit formula for the order of the group formed by this divisors?

Comment: You could have a look at the book

Modular Units
Daniel S. Kubert, Serge Lang 

specifically the chapter 

The Cuspidal Divisor Class Group on X(N)

Good luck !